# regex in python for number followed by letter, allowing for float

Tags: python, regex

What would be the correct regex expression for splitting something like `'32s'` into `(32, 's')` in Python while also allowing to split something like `'31.7435x'` into `(31.7435, 'x')`?

I was using `re.findall('(\d+|[A-Za-z]+)', '32s')`, but this doesn't allow for floats, whereas `'(\d+\.\d+|[A-Za-z]+)'` doesn't allow for ints. Trying `'(\d+|[A-Za-z]+)|(\d+\.\d+|[A-Za-z]+)'` also doesn't work.

Comment: `(\d+|\d+\.[\d]*)([A-Za-z]+)`  - you were close, but the parentheses `( )` go around the groups you want to capture

Comment: A question being put on hold is something not to mind, as long as (1) you get your answer; (2) the broad point of the question is already represented on Stack Overflow. Does the solution in the above comment work?

Comment: Yes the solution works. Sorry, not sure what you mean about "A question being put on hold".